# Remove a word from Stock dictionary

Tags: dictionary

When I write the word "OK" in Swedish it says "Ook" which doesn't mean anything in swedish. **I haven't added this ook myself** so I can't find it in "Personal dictionary". I wonder if it is possible to simply remove this strange word that comes with the stock swedish dictionary?

Perhaps I should add that I use the new Nexus 4 google phone with latest everything.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually managed to temporarily solve this: add OK to your personal dictionary and be done with it.