# Ultimate solution to delete a word from Android slide keyboard's core dictionary

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, keyboard, auto-correct, dictionary

Everytime I write my daughter's name (`Ala`) on my Galaxy Nexus (with Android 4.3), slide keyboard always corrects that to `Alla`. There is no such word in Polish (used by me) language / directory. And this word in 100% not added by me to user-directory. It is in core directory, that slide keyboard uses.

I think, I passed through all similar questions here (see resume below) and still found not solution. So, I have to ask again: **How can I remove a word, that is incorrect and shouldn't be in dictionary?**

So far, I've tried:

- [checking both personal and general dictionary](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/48992/20449): word, I won't to remove / is incorrect isn't there,
- [typing and correcting word many times, so keyboard / dictionary "learns", what I want](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/51214/20449): I'm writing and correcting this (and others, that are incorrect) word for as long as I have  slide keyboard on my Galaxy Nexus; that would be about 1,5 year now; no luck -- it's still there,
- [adding correct word to personal directory](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/46793/20449): I've added correct word months ago; still no luck,
- [wiping out Google Keyboard cache](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/61125/20449), though I still haven't tried wiping data, as I'm pretty sure (as per comments), that I'll loose all my personal dictionaries, not getting anything in exchange -- incorrecto word seems to be in Android's slide keyboard's core directory,
- [long pressing correct / incorrect word to get to `delete` option](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/61214/20449): no way, there is no such option anywhere; all, that I see, are just other suggestions to typed / corrected word,
- [clearing Search engine storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/75682/20449): I doubt, this could do anything, but I tried that as well; no effect,
- [removing incorrect word from my personal dictionary](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/61120/20449): since, this word is not there.

Things, that I didn't try or I failed trying:

- [removing all updates to Google Keyboard](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/64218/20449): I didn't found proper option to do so; another thing, that I hardly doubt, if uninstalling software updates has any impact on core dictionary,
- [deselecting Google Voice Guide](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/80926/20449): cause, again, I didn't found, where to to that and because I doubt, this has any relevance to my question / problem.

Anyone knows a solution, that I haven't tested, that works on Galaxy Nexus / Android 4.3?

Situation is the same, as pictured in [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/61115/20449) (only I have Android 4.3), so I won't repeat nearly the same screenshots. Slide keyboard is correcting my entires all the time to some strange / incorrect words and none of this words are in my personal dictionary. So, I'm looking for a solution (if any exists) to remove these words from keyboard's core dictionary.